# How to implement HttpPatch action method in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API without using NewtonSoft

Tags: json, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, system.text.json

Yesterday I upgraded my ASP.NET Core 5 Web API to .Net 6. Today I thought I'd also migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json.

The first thing I did was to remove the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package from my project. I also removed the `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` statement from the `services.AddControllers()` part of `Startup.cs`.

I then renamed all `using Newtonsoft.Json;` to `using System.Text.Json;`, all `[JsonProperty]` decorators to `[JsonPropertyName]`, etc, etc.

I'm almost error-free now, but I've hit a stumbling block with my HttpPatch action methods. The "ModelState" class seems to be a member of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`, which I removed. I could re-add it, as well as re-add `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` to `services.AddControllers()` in `Startup.cs`, but that would seem a step backward in what I'm trying to achieve (which is to completely cut off from Newtonsoft.Json).

This is the error VS is showing:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary' to 'System.Action<Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchError>'

Any ideas on how I can make HttpPatch work without depending on Newtonsoft.Json?

My HttpPatch action method looks like this:

```
[HttpPatch("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<DocGroup>> PatchDocumentGroup([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<DocGroup> patchDoc)
{
    if (patchDoc == null)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    var documentGroup = await _context.DocGroups.FindAsync(id);

    if (documentGroup == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    patchDoc.ApplyTo(documentGroup, ModelState);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new ObjectResult(documentGroup);
}
```

Comment: From the docs I see that HttpPatch is only viable with NewtonsoftJson -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-6.0. Maybe try with HttpPut? This is a good article about it https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/httpput-or-httppatch-in-asp-net-core-ceaae99e320b

Comment: does this will help? https://code-maze.com/using-httpclient-to-send-http-patch-requests-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thanx for the reply @PowerMouse. One thing I see in the link u sent is that they omit the ModelState parameter from the patchDoc.ApplyTo() method. Indeed, I noticed yesterday this argument was optional, & removed it, which allowed the app to compile and run. But when performing a PATCH request to the API, i then got this error:

The JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.JsonPatchDocument

I searched this & it turns out its because I removed the Newtonsoft.Json package.

Anyway, Im now looking at this article as an option:

Comment: Oops, forgot to post the link for the article I mentioned in my previous comment. It's: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.0#jsonpatch-addnewtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson

Comment: i dont understand the issue, why not use Newtonsoft, but try Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, ASP.NET Core doesn't support `JSON Patch` without `Newtonsoft.Json`, take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12994#issuecomment-521031088) from the official repo. On the other hand, you can use [this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-support-for-json-patch-when-using-systemtextjson) to add support for `JSON Patch` using `Newtonsoft.Json`, while leaving the other input and output formatters unchanged:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, MyJPIF.GetJsonPatchInputFormatter());
});
```

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace JsonPatchSample;

public static class MyJPIF
{
    public static NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter GetJsonPatchInputFormatter()
    {
        var builder = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging()
            .AddMvc()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson()
            .Services.BuildServiceProvider();

        return builder
            .GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>()
            .Value
            .InputFormatters
            .OfType<NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter>()
            .First();
    }
}
```

That way, `NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter` will process the `JSON Patch` requests, and the existing `System.Text.Json`-based input and formatters will process all other JSON requests and responses.

Comment: Thanks Luiz, that's basically what I ended up doing, but not as elegantly as in your suggestion :)